# Contact form 7 send the form once, although the client of several clicks

Tags: jquery, wordpress, contact-form-7

I need to control send form, because the customer give many clicks and the form send many times I try to blocked the button send with the first click, I try this:

method 1

```
jQuery( ".wpcf7-form " ).submit(function(){
          jQuery('input#form1').attr('disabled','disabled');            
    });
```

method 2

```
    document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) {  
        jQuery('input#form1').attr('disabled','disabled');
    
}, true );
```

method 3

```
    jQuery( ".wpcf7-submit " ).submit(function(){   
                    
        jQuery('input#form1').attr('disabled','disabled');
        
    });
```

documentation: https://contactform7.com/dom-events/

The methods don't work.

Answer (score 1):

this is the method that worked for me.

```
jQuery(document).on('submit','form',function(){   
    jQuery('input#form1').attr('disabled','disabled');  
});
```

Comment: This looks like it just copies Tony's answer, just with more generic values in the function calls. Please edit the answer to clarify how this works and what it does.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the button itself on click:

```
jQuery( '.wpcf7-submit' ).on( 'click', function() {     
     jQuery( '.wpcf7-submit' ).attr( 'disabled', 'disabled' ); 
} );
```

This assumes that your submit button is `.wpcf7-submit`.  I'd personally check the ID of the submit button and use that rather than the class.

Comment: hi Tony Djukic,  i try your code but, when i send the message the form does not work. it stop

Comment: Make sure you're targeting the right IDs and classes.  I can't see your HTML so I'm not entirely sure those are the correct elements being called.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it so that people can't submit the form while the "Ajax Spinner" is present, by disabling the click of the button.

```
// Prevent Multiple Clicks on Contact Form 7 Submissions
jQuery(document).on('click', '.wpcf7-submit', function(e){
     if( jQuery('.ajax-loader').hasClass('is-active') ) {
          e.preventDefault();
          return false;
     }
});
```